# R date m/d/y to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I am trying to change my date within my dataframe into the correct format within R. (m/d/y to the correct yyyy-mm-dd).

I have data that looks like this

```
    Date      Time  pH
1   1/4/1981  9:00  3.9 
2   1/8/1981  8:30  3.9
```

etc

The name of my data frame I am working in is data.cat.AC

I tried

```
data.cat.AC[,1]$Date <- as.Date(data.cat.AC[,1]$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

...but this did not work.

I am getting the error,

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any tips or pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use as.Date, you should not enter the format that you want as output. Instead enter the format as it is in the data.

```
as.Date("1/4/1981", format="%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "1981-01-04"
```

We got lucky in this case in that your desired output happens to be the default output. But for learning purposes, let's say you wanted the format "dd:mm:YYYY". After converting to `Date` format as we did above, we would use:

```
format(x2, "%m:%d:%Y")
[1] "01:04:1981"
```

Comment: You are subsetting two times. Use either `data.cat.AC[,1]` or `data.cat.AC$Date`, not both.